# Wordpress Menu bar working fine in desktop resizing, but not on mobile browser

Tags: android, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I am currently working on my WordPress site which has javascript plugin MeanMenu bundled. It is working fine when I resize the screen to mobile size but on my Android or iPhone device not working at all . It is supposed to get toggled and opened on click.

[image: website on android device(Samsung galaxy s7)]

The screen breakpoint is set at 767 for small screens. Viewport meta tag is also added.

Cannot figure out what could be the issue...Please help!!

Thanks,
nskp

Comment: the website is  www.rafiki.ca

Comment: css, html, js ? share something please. share your media queries...

Answer (score -1):

"@media (min-width:768px)" this seems not correct. change to something like this: "@media screen and (min-width: 768px) "

Comment: Do yu mean max-width? because its for mobile that it is not working